# Split a specific text in a string

Tags: javascript

I have this problem below that I want to split a string with a specific character/text on it. I made this code below as my scenario if my string has my split `string (or)`.

**Desired Output**

> A1 Hello World
>
> A2 Hello World!.

But as you can see in my sample code it split all `or` that he sees in my string.

```js
var str = "A1 Hello World or A2 Hello World!.";
var split = str.split('or');

console.log(split);
```

Can it be also possible that the `or` in a string can be change the colour into black?. My default colour text is green. Something like this below code.

**Note**

Code below is related above code

```html
<a style="color:green">A1 Hello World</a> or <a style="color:green">A2 Hello World!.</a>
```

My string data is not fix that I declare in javascript. It came from database through a loop. Above string is just a sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split by `' or '` instead, surrounded by spaces:

```js
var str = "A1 Hello World or A2 Hello World!.";
var split = str.split(' or ');

console.log(split);
```

To replace with `span`s, you can use a regular expression which captures the non- `' or '` phrases in one group, captures the `' or '` phrase in the second group, and replaces with the first group inside a `span`, followed by the second group:

```js
var str = "A1 Hello World or A2 Hello World!.";
console.log(str.replace(/(.+?)( or |$)/g, '<a style="color:green">$1</a>$2'))
```

Comment: ill try it..wait a bit

Comment: just a question only. This the on how to display my text in the html. How to color the `or` word into black?. In my current codes its green. `row =  + '<div class="col-md-10"> ' + Desc.replace(/(.+?)( or |$)/g, '<a style="color:orange">$1</a><a style="color:green">$2</a>') + ' </div >'`

Comment: I don't think it's possible in a single regular expression - you'll have to `.replace` twice. First use the original regex, and then replace `' or '`s by wrapping them in some element with `color:black` or whichever you want.

Comment: can u give an example?. I don't know how to use regular expression

Comment: The same way the first substrings were replaced - match the `or`s and replace with something like `<span style="somestyle">$&</span>` or whatever you need. `$1` represents the first captured group, `$&` represents the whole matched string.

Answer (score 1):

Should be like:

```js
var str = "A1 Hello World or A2 Hello World!.";
var split = str.split(' or ');

console.log(split);
```

Answer (score 1):

use space

```js
var str = "A1 Hello World or A2 Hello World!.";
var split = str.split(' or ');

console.log(split);
```