# How to color a specific text using regular expression

Tags: javascript

I'm new to regular expression and I can't understand it well on how it works. It solves my first issue from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52396676/split-a-specific-text-in-a-string). But my problem now is that I want to color the two string separately. The other one is orange and other one is green. But code below is it color the text into orange. And for the `or` word it is possible to color it as black?.

```js
 var str = 'A2 Award Notice or A2 Lease Contract';
 var row = '<div class="row mt-2" style="font-size:20px">'
            + '<div class="col-md-1"><input class="chckDocument  form-control flat" type="checkbox" style="height:20px; -webkit-box-shadow:none" class="form-control flat mt-2"> </div >'
            + '<div class="col-md-1"> <input type="file" data-type="" data-name="" id="' + 1 + '" class="btnClickHello d-none" value="Upload"><label for="' + 1 + '" class="btn btn-default">Upload</label></div>'
             + '<div class="col-md-10"> ' + str.replace(/(.+?)( or |$)/g, '<a style="color:orange">$1</a> <a style="color:green">$2</a>') + ' </div >'
              + '</div >';
                                        
          
$("#divID").append(row);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divID"></div>
```

**Expected Output**

> A2 Award Notice  <<-- color (green or orange)
>
> or               <<-- color black
>
> A2 Lease Contract <<-- color (green or orange)

Comment: What determines the colour each string should have, can they be the same colour, do they have to be different, will, or can, there ever be three or more matches?

Comment: the string that separate by `or` must be different colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need *two* `.replace`s - a single one isn't enough, at least not without a callback function. First surround everything outside the `' or '`s with your `a`s, and then `.replace` the resulting string again: search for `/ or /g` and replace with something like `<span style="color:black">$&</span>`, which will replace all instances of `' or '` with that `' or '` enclosed in a `<span>`.

That takes care of the `or`. For the other parts of the string, a plain regular expression alone won't work (at least not in Javascript) - to replace with something *different* on each match, declare an array of the colors you want to be able to use, and use a callback function that takes an item from the colors array to set as the `color`:

```js
var str = 'A2 Award Notice or A2 Lease Contract';
const colors = ['green', 'orange'];
const replacedStr = str
  .replace(/(.+?)( or |$)/g, (_, g1, g2) => {
    const [color] = colors.splice(0, 1);
    return `<a style="color:${color}">${g1}</a>${g2}`;
  })
  .replace(/ or /g, '<span style="color:black">$&</span>');
console.log(replacedStr);

var row = '<div class="row mt-2" style="font-size:20px">' +
  '<div class="col-md-1"><input class="chckDocument  form-control flat" type="checkbox" style="height:20px; -webkit-box-shadow:none" class="form-control flat mt-2"> </div >' +
  '<div class="col-md-1"> <input type="file" data-type="" data-name="" id="' + 1 + '" class="btnClickHello d-none" value="Upload"><label for="' + 1 + '" class="btn btn-default">Upload</label></div>' +
  '<div class="col-md-10"> ' + replacedStr + ' </div >' +
  '</div >';


$("#divID").append(row);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divID"></div>
```

Comment: I've tried what you said. And its okay. But the two text must have different color.